# How to serialize models without field names in the JSON output

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a class and serializer like so:

```
class MyProperties(models.Model):   
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)     
   value = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

class MyPropertiesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = MyProperties
       fields = ('name', 'value')
```

It's simply a properties table which has a key/value pair(simplified for this SO question).

I want to serialize this model *without* having the field names in the output.

Looking at [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#serializers) and [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/) did not provide me a way to create the following output:

Say I have two rows in my DB table:

```
| name   | value    |
|--------|:--------:|
| width  | 7 feet   |
| height | 10 feet  |
```

My desired output looks like this:

```
[
  {"width":"7 feet"}, 
  {"height": "10 feet"}
}
```

Instead,using the examples I see in the pages I referenced and the example serializer I posted, I get something like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "width", 
    "value": "7 feet"
  },
  {
    "name": "height",
    "value": "10 feet"
  }
]
```

How would I create a serializer which will give me the desired output format?

Comment: For other readers I'm cross-linking to the discussion group topic on this: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/django-rest-framework/k-T-C_5O2SA

Comment: @TomChristie Feel free to submit that link as an answer. I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

See Tom Christie's comment above. He is the writer of DRF and his suggestion is way better than this.

---

You might use a [custom Renderer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#custom-renderers) and manipulate the output data before it's rendered. Like this:

```
class CustomRenderer(renderers.JSONRenderer):
    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        result = {}
        for item in data: 
            result[item['name']] = item['value'] 

        data = result
        return super(CustomRenderer, self).render(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
```

And use it in your view:

```
class YourView(generics.ListAPIView):
    renderer_classes = (CustomRenderer, renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer)
```